# React hook useCallback with get API call inside useEffect not behaving correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect, usecallback

I want to achieve the following.

Action from `redux` is imported in this component. It fetches data from firebase, which I use as a database. Data is displayed inside this component.

My problem is that data is fetched every time component is mounted, which is not an ideal scenario.

I would like to prevent that behavior.

Ideal scenario is that data should be fetched only first time component is rendered and no more afterwards. Of course it should also fetch when data is changed otherwise no. I used `useCallback`, but certainly there is a mistake in the code below. Token and Id are passed when user is authenticated.

```
import { fetchFavs } from "../../store/actions";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";


const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);
  const id = useSelector((state) => state.auth.userId);
  const fetchedFavs = useSelector((state) => state.saveFavs.fetchedFavs);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

const fetchFavsOptimized = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(fetchFavs(token, id));
    console.log("rendered");
  }, [token, id, dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      fetchFavsOptimized();
    }
  }, [fetchFavsOptimized, token]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this, one explicit and one implicit.

The explicit way would be to add a new boolean item in your redux store and check against that every time you load your component to see if you should load the data from the db or not.

So your redux store may have a new key/value: `dataLoaded: false`;
In your component now you need to load this from your redux store and check against it in your use effect:

```
const dataLoaded = useSelector((state) => state.dataLoaded);

useEffect(() => {
    if (token && !dataLoaded) {
      fetchFavsOptimized();
    }
  }, [fetchFavsOptimized, token, dataLoaded]);
```

Don't forget in your **fetchFavsOptimized** function to update the **dataLoaded** to **true** after the loading of the data from the db is complete.
This has the upside that every time you want to load the db from the db again you simply need to set **dataLoaded** to **false**.

The implicit way is to check the data length and if that is 0 then execute the load. Assuming that you store data in your redux store in this form: `data: []` and your data is an array (you could do the same thing by initiating data as **null** and check if data !== null) your component would look like this:

```
const data = useSelector((state) => state.data);

useEffect(() => {
    if (token && data.length === 0) {
      fetchFavsOptimized();
    }
  }, [fetchFavsOptimized, token, data]);
```

Keep in mind that I wouldn't do it like that because if you don't have any data you may end up with an infinite loop, but it's a good technique to use in other cases.

Comment: Just one question about the explicit approach. What if fetched data is changed because dataLoaded stays true and it won't fetch again. Am I right?

Comment: How to know if sth in data is changed from the last render?

Comment: The best way would be to create a new redux action to update the dataLoaded freely. So when you perform an update you will execute that redux action and set dataLoaded to false. This way next time you load the component it will fetch the data again.

Comment: To know if sth in the data is changed you need to know what other actions in your app update these data and every time one such action is executed set dataLoaded to false.

Comment: I think I get it. I will try to implement it.

Comment: I implemented dataLoaded and change its value depending on fetched data change. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

For fetching only once on component mounting: (mind `[]`)

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchFavsOptimized()
}, []) // <- this empty square brackets allow for one execution during mounting
```

I'm not sure, but the issue of continous calling of `useEffect` might be `[fetchFavsOptimized, token]`. Placing `fetchFavsOptimized` function in `[]` might not be the best way.

You want to fetch, when data changes, but what data? You mean `token` ? Or something else?

`React.useEffect()` hook alows for fetching when data changes with placing this changable data in `[here_data]` of `useEffect`. Example:

```js
const [A, setA] = React.useState();

React.useEffect(() => {
    // this block of code will be executed when state 'A' is changed
},[A])
```

The best practise of using `useEffect` is to separate the conditions in runs with.
If You need to fetch on some `data change` AND on `component mount`, write `TWO` `useEffect` fuctions. Separate for `data change` and `component mount`.

Comment: I just want to fetch the first time component is mounted.  When I visit the route of that component if my fetched data is not changed I would like not to fetch it again. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: This is not correct, The code will still execute every time the component is loaded, it just won't execute on every render update.

Comment: @StavrosAngelis I want to fetch only when that fetched data is changed, otherwise just first time component is rendered.

Comment: ` I would like this to fetch only first time component is rendered and no more.` quoting OP

Comment: @Chaka15 check my answer.

Comment: @Wiktoor yes so every time the user navigates to the component it will reload, which is not what the OP want's since he/she stores the data in their redux store.

Comment: @Chaka15 to make `useEffect` execute only once, in the component mounting use `[]` (empty square brackets) the way I showed above. It will call Your fetch only once, when You enter a page (and on every page reload).

Comment: @Wiktoor but that's the point. I don't want to fetch on page reload if data in it is the same as before.